# How to make serializer to accept id insted of url for related object.

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have simple model with a relation to User.

serializes looks like:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('task_date', 'type_type', 'category', 'customer_login', 'customer_id', 'text', 'active', 'created', 'updated', 'crated_by', 'assignet_to')
```

How do I make it accept `ID` instead of url (`http://localhost:8888/users/1/`) for related objects. For example, I have `assigned_to` field and I want It to pass validation if I provide just `id` of related object.

Answer (score 1):

I so I just needed to use `serializers.ModelSerializer` instead of `serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer`.

More about it [[here]](http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis.html)